# Pycharm and virtual environment

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, virtualenv

I created virtual environment called `tensorflow` in Anaconda.

Now I would like to use it in Pycharm (I have 2017 version of Pycharm)

In Pycharm in project interpreter I selected standard Anaconda interpreter. In terminal inside Pycharm I typed `activate tensorflow` and it successfully activated, but when I try to run `import tensorflow as tf` it generates error: `No module named 'tensorflow'`

I already searched and tried everything in SO. I have virtual env. enabled in tools -> terminal.

Any thoughts?

**Addition:** I have not problem using this virtual environment within jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of activating your interpreter in Pycharm, you should select your interpreter from the environment you just created. Basically, when you create a new project, you should select your interpreter from the virtual environment as opposed to the standard anaconda environment. An example is shown in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, my virtual env. was hard to find on Windows